# Should I close a DBCursor in a method after it is no longer needed or can I leave it up to the garbage collectior?

Tags: java, mongodb, grails

I have a grails application that is using Mongodb as a datastore. I have some methods on the server side that require a [dbcursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) to be iterated over.

The cursor could be very large. i.e over 20k entries.

After iterating over the cursor some of my methods contai additional logic. Is it best preactice to close the cursor using the close() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to close it manually.  GC will not call close() for you and it will orphan that cursor.

Comment: There is actually a finalizer on DBCursor, but the JVM offers no guarantees about when or if it will ever be run, so the advice still stands.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, anything you open, or cause to be opened you should also close.